# Extra methods in drived class of abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I am aware that this question has been asked many times. But looking at the answers I couldn't find the right one or working one that suits me.

Let's say I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class EntityService<T>
{
     public T GetAll()
     {
         //Implementation
     }
}
```

Then I have a drived class

```
public class UserService : EntityService<User>
{
      public User GetAll(string Orderby)
      {
          //Implementation
      }
}
```

And I create a static variable of the UserService for to use it through out my project.

```
public static readonly EntityService<User> UserService = new UserService();
```

Using `UserService.GetAll();` would work perfectly fine. However when I want to use `UserService.GetAll("Acsending");` would given an compiler error saying this method does not exist. I know I have to cast it to UserService Type but I couldn't do it. Where I put (UserService) It always gave errors and I am wondering is there a better way to do this without casting it since I want to write my code plain and simple as possible.

Comment: You are resolving to an instance of EntityService.  Why would you expect that you'd be able to call a method in UserService?

Comment: Then how I am supposed to use the extra methods in drived classes?

Comment: @EgeAydın By casting.

Comment: Didn't you read the question? I am asking if there is a better way? And I tried to cast it but compiler did not accept that.

Comment: @EgeAydın Yes, I read the question. I'm simply answering the question from your comment. If I wanted to answer your original question, I would have added an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: You should be injecting your UserService instance into the classes that need it rather than exposing it as a global variable (specifically a global variable resolved to your base type).  That way you get the full functionality that you need where you need it without exposing unnecessary details to other areas of your application.

Comment: I do not agree. Because my service classes are needed in most of my application. I am confused though. Then only time we need static object is when we want to use them only if we want to use them in everywhere.

Comment: @Jashaszun you are right man, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either declare the variable as the subclass like this:

```
public static readonly UserService userService = new UserService();
```

Or, you downcast every time you want to use the `EntityService<User>` as UserService:

```
var userServiceDownCast = (UserService)userService;
userServiceDownCast.GetAll("Ascending");
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantages for using the first approach?

Comment: Not really.
If you need the UserService as EntityService again, you can always upcast it like this:
(EntityService<User>)userService;

Comment: Allright thank you. I seems to be working as I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 2):

I think for your situation will be useful to do it like this, sorry that a little bit late, but:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    User GetAll();

    User GetAll(string OrderBy);
}

public abstract class EntityService<T>
{
    public T GetAll()
    {
       //Implementation
    }
}

public class UserService : EntityService<User>, IUserService
{
    public User GetAll(string OrderBy) 
    {
       //Implementation
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
public static readonly IUserService UserService = new UserService();
....
UserService.GetAll();
UserService.GetAll("orderByColumn");
```

And then if you want some common code for Entities, you can write something like this:

```
 void ForEntityMethod(EntityService<T> entityService)
```

If special for Users i.e.:

```
 void ForUserMethod(IUserService userService)
```

It think it give you more flexibility and avoid cast in your situation.
Also exist another good variants, but they are can be used if you have some future vision of system.

Comment: `public static readonly UserService userService = new UserService();` I am currently using them like this. Can you tell me why your solution might be better?

Comment: Because you will programming on interface level, that's almost in all situations are better then your variant. Maybe in future, of course if you want, you can add DI to your project, that's also can be helpful. I wrote examples with using new style for Entities and Users, which are clear your logic and separating concerns, avoid cast and give you possibility control available methods in UserService via IUserService interface. Is it enough?)